# Get the row with latest date after inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    achievements.id,
    achievements.name,
    achievements.category,
    userAchievements.createdAt
FROM
    achievements
        INNER JOIN
    userAchievements ON userAchievements.achievementId = achievements.id
        AND userAchievements.userId = 12
WHERE
    achievements.type = 2
```

Result of this query is:

| id | name | category | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | First | 1 | 2021-02-11 |
| 13 | Second | 2 | 2021-02-12 |
| 14 | Third | 4 | 2021-03-01 |
| 15 | Fourth | 4 | 2021-03-02 |

I have to leave only unique category with max createdAt field.

I need a query that will give the following result:

| id | name | category | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | First | 1 | 2021-02-11 |
| 13 | Second | 2 | 2021-02-12 |
| 15 | Fourth | 4 | 2021-03-02 |

If I use `group by` then it returns row with id 14.

MySQL version - 5.7.33.

Achievements table:

| id | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | First | 1 |
| 13 | Second | 2 |
| 14 | Third | 4 |
| 15 | Fourth | 4 |

UserAchievements table:

| id | achievementId | userId | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 8 | 12 | 2021-02-11 |
| 7 | 13 | 12 | 2021-02-12 |
| 36 | 15 | 12 | 2021-03-02 |
| 40 | 14 | 12 | 2021-03-01 |

P.S.
I managed to write a query that solves the problem

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *,
            IF(@prev <> category, @rn:=0, @rn),
            @prev:=category,
            @rn:=@rn + 1 AS rn
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        achievements.id,
            achievements.name,
            achievements.category,
            userAchievements.createdAt
    FROM
        achievements
    INNER JOIN userAchievements ON userAchievements.achievementId = achievements.id
        AND userAchievements.userId = 12
    WHERE
        achievements.type = 2) as ach, (SELECT @rn:=0) rn, (SELECT @prev:='') prev
    ORDER BY ach.createdAt DESC) t
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

Comment: Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina 5.7.33 version

Comment: Please provide sample data as well as desired results.

Comment: You may: emulate ROW_NUMBER() using user-defined variables; use 2 copies of your query, in one of them group the data by category selection maximal date and use this pair for to select the row from another copy.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated the main post

Comment: Use distinct + sorting by date desc

Comment: @Akina Can you show me an example?

Comment: @Akina I updated main post with example of emulate ROW_NUMBER(). 
Can you tell me what is wrong with the query?

Comment: *Can you tell me what is wrong with the query?* JOIN. If you use UDV for ROW_NUMBER emulation then you must have only one source table. If you need to enumerate joined data then join in subquery then apply UDV technique to this subquery as the only source in outer query.

Comment: @Akina Thanks, I fiext the query and everything worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.category ORDER BY a.created_at DESC) as seqnum
      FROM achievements JOIN
           userAchievements ua
           ON ua.achievementId = a.id AND
              ua.userId = 12
      WHERE a.type = 2
     ) a
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I am using MySQL and it doesn’t allow such a construction.

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY a.category ORDER BY a.created_at DESC) as seqnum       FROM achiev' at line 3

Comment: @AndreyKalenyuk . . . No.  You are using an old version of MySQL.  MySQL has supported window functions for about three years.

Comment: I need a solution for version 5.7.33 unfortunately.
@Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

This subquery basically search for all maximum dates, grouped by category.

```
SELECT MAX(_ua.createdAt) FROM `achievements` _a INNER JOIN user_achievements _ua ON _a.id = _ua.achievementId group by _a.category
```

So you maybe you can do :

```
SELECT a.* FROM achievements a
INNER JOIN user_achievements ua ON a.id = ua.achievementId 
AND ua.createdAt IN (SELECT MAX(_ua.createdAt) FROM `achievements` _a INNER JOIN 
user_achievements _ua ON _a.id = _ua.achievementId group by _a.category)
```

Comment: This query return only 1 row